# Passing a return `NSString` variable from a class ( `+(id)` ) to another view controller class

Tags: instance-variables

Passing a return `NSString` variable from a class ( `+(id)` ) to another view controller class, as a result, it returned NIL by using `NSLog`.

Is there any concepts I missed?

sharedFile.h

```
......
@property (nonmatic, retain) NSString *returnDB;
+(id)chkDB:(NSString *)returnDB;
......
```

sharedFile.m

```
+(id)chkDB:(NSString *)returnDB{
    ........something......
    return returnDB;
}
```

viewController1.m

```
import "sharedFile.h"
......
NSString *returnDB = [[NSString alloc] init];
[sharedFile chkDb:returnDB];
NSLog(@"result: %@", returnDB];
```

Comment: From above codebase,you are allocate a NSString and pass to method.As the method is returning an NSString but you have not handle the returning variable.And printing the value of NSString which is allocated.You should collect the return value in returnDB and print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle your method result:

```
NSString *returnDB = [[NSString alloc] init];
returnDB = [sharedFile chkDb:returnDB];
NSLog(@"result: %@", returnDB);
```

Comment: Thanks so much, i missed the second row of your answer. It works perfectly now.